# Receiving wrong subject

Tags: python, smtplib

I'm using this code to send email and it works, but when I receive email the subject looks like this and also has no message:

```
" No subject"
afsagsag@gmail.com To: Subject: OMG Super Important Message Good morning, <afsagsag@gmail.com>
```

```
import smtplib
import carriers
def amtg():
    gmail_user = 'sgfsfsfsf@gmail.com'
    gmail_password = 'rtgassds'

    sent_from = gmail_user
    to = ['sgssfsd@gmail.com']
    subject = 'OMG Super Important Message'
    body = carriers.rsting + carriers.amtg1

    email_text = """\
    From: %s
    To: %s
    subject: %s
    %s
    """ % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
        server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
        server.close()

        print ('Email sent!')
    except:
        print ('Something went wrong...')
```

Comment: You are not passing any subject to `sever.sendmail`.

Comment: @mkrieger1 , can you explain more? Im few days in python and still dont get what im doing)

Comment: I actually don't know how to use `sendmail` with a specific subject, but it seems to me that it just sends the string `email_text` as the body of the message.

Comment: @mkriefer1 it works properly when i remove 'def amtg():' but i need that function to use in different module

Comment: It has to be empty line between headers (From, To, Subject) and body.

Comment: you can also see examples for standard module [email](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html#email-examples)